# ActiveMq integration with Spring 2.5

Tags: java, spring, jms, activemq-classic

I am using ActiveMq 5.32 with Spring 2.5.5.  I use pretty generic configuration, as long as I include the
jmsTransactionManager in DefaultMessageListenerContainer, Spring throw an error on start up:

"Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer#0'"

Without the transactionManager attribute , this works fine, but when I add 10 messages to the message queue, a transaction exception will occur.

Part of my configurations :

```
<bean class="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer">
                <property name="connectionFactory" ref="connectionFactory" />
                <property name="destination" ref="emailDestination" />
                <property name="messageListener" ref="emailServiceMDP" />
                <property name="transactionManager" ref="jmsTransactionManager" />
</bean>

<bean id="jmsTransactionManager" class="org.springframework.jms.connection.JmsTransactionManager">
                <property name="connectionFactory" ref="connectionFactory" />
</bean>
```

Does this version of Spring and Activemq has some know issues in integration ? Or do I need additional libs to get jmsTransactionManager to work ?

Updated: full stack trace :

> 21:36:21 ERROR Context initialization
>   failed
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name
>   'org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer#0'
>   defined in ServletContext resource
>   [/WEB-INF/config/spring/component/applicationContext-jms-activemq5.xml]:
>   Invocation of init method failed;
>   nested exception is
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationUtils.sameResourceFactory(Lorg/springframework/transaction/support/ResourceTransactionManager;Ljava/lang/Object;)Z
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1337)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:473)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
>     at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native
>   Method)   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:380)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:264)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:221)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:261)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:185)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:164)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:429)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:729)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:381)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:255)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:199)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:45)
>     at
>   com.suzsoft.framework.spring.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:23)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:3934)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4429)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:791)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:771)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:526)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:987)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectories(HostConfig.java:909)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:495)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1206)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:314)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1053)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:722)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:443)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:516)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:710)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:583)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
>   Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:288)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:413)
>   Caused by:
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationUtils.sameResourceFactory(Lorg/springframework/transaction/support/ResourceTransactionManager;Ljava/lang/Object;)Z
>     at
>   org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.initialize(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:190)
>     at
>   org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer.initialize(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:459)
>     at
>   org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractJmsListeningContainer.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractJmsListeningContainer.java:135)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1368)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1334)
>     ... 40 more May 25, 2010 9:36:21 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext
>   listenerStart SEVERE: Exception
>   sending context initialized event to
>   listener instance of class
>   com.suzsoft.framework.spring.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name
>   'org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer#0'
>   defined in ServletContext resource
>   [/WEB-INF/config/spring/component/applicationContext-jms-activemq5.xml]:
>   Invocation of init method failed;
>   nested exception is
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationUtils.sameResourceFactory(Lorg/springframework/transaction/support/ResourceTransactionManager;Ljava/lang/Object;)Z
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1337)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:473)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
>     at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native
>   Method)   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:380)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:264)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:221)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:261)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:185)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:164)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:429)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:729)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:381)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:255)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:199)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:45)
>     at
>   com.suzsoft.framework.spring.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:23)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:3934)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4429)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:791)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:771)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:526)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:987)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectories(HostConfig.java:909)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:495)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1206)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:314)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1053)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:722)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:443)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:516)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:710)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:583)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
>   Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:288)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:413)
>   Caused by:
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationUtils.sameResourceFactory(Lorg/springframework/transaction/support/ResourceTransactionManager;Ljava/lang/Object;)Z
>     at
>   org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.initialize(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:190)
>     at
>   org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer.initialize(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:459)
>     at
>   org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractJmsListeningContainer.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractJmsListeningContainer.java:135)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1368)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1334)
>     ... 40 more

Comment: The error you get on startup should contain a lot more information such as nested exceptions, causes, etc. do you have this? Spring should be telling you *why* it failed to create that bean, which will help point you in the correct direction of what to fix.

Comment: Yes matt, but I can't get any useful infomation about this error, I updated my post to include full stack trace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the true problem in that stack trace:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationUtils.sameResourceFactory(Lorg/springframework/transaction/support/ResourceTransactionManager;Ljava/lang/Object;)Z at
```

The problem is that whatever version of the spring-tx jar you have on the classpath does not contain the class/method `TransactionSynchronizationUtils.sameResourceFactory`. As best as I can determine, that method [did exist in Spring 2.5.4](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework/spring-tx/2.5.4/org/springframework/transaction/support/TransactionSynchronizationUtils.java) but [did not exist in Spring 2.5.3](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework/spring-tx/2.5.3/org/springframework/transaction/support/TransactionSynchronizationUtils.java/). I think you need to check your classpath to see which versions of the various Spring jars you are actually using.

FWIW, ActiveMQ currently uses 2.5.6 internally and previous used Spring 2.5.5. That's what I can recall off the top of my head, further back then that I would need to do some real digging.

Hope that helps.

Bruce

Comment: Thank you so much, Bruce, you really saved my life, as I updated my spring-tx jar to 2.5.6 the error disappered!

Comment: This is really weird, I only successfully start once, then I still got the same error. I am using spring 2.5.5, as you said this method existed in 2.5.4, when checked out the source, in 2.5.5 this method still existed, I don't know why it reported cant find error.